# Is it possible to connect WebSocket enabled backend to AWS WebSocket API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

I have a backend service running on EC2/EKS with only websocket protocol enabled.

As far as I saw, AWS Websocket API gateway proxies WS call to HTTP for backend. Is it possible for the Websocket gateway to act just as a proxy, do only authorization, and send requests to backend WS calls as well?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that websocket api can act just as a proxy and do only authorization. Instead try using a public facing alb with cognito for authorization
[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77303315/web-socket-authentication-using-aws-application-load-balancer-alb-api-gatewa/77373543#77373543)